# libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: basic_string

Tags: c++, string, vector, stringstream

I'm trying to read a .CSV file and I'm encountering errors with reading strings.

For context, this .CSV file contains a person's name followed by a few personality traits (e.g., likes cats, chocolate, mountains, etc.). I want to read in this data and store it in a `map<string, vector<string> >` where the person's name is the key and the value is a vector with each personality trait in it.

I'm using the following code, but the moment I uncomment the line `stringstream s(line);`, I get this error:

libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: basic_string

Could anyone tell me what this error means, why I'm getting it, and how to avoid getting it in the future? Any help is appreciated c:

P.S. I've also included the rest of the function commented out so you can see what the finished product is supposed to do. Here's some sample data that I made up:

```
John,Dog,DC,Beach,Hamburgers,Brownies
Sue,Cat,DC,Beach,Hot Dogs,Brownies
Jim,Dog,Marvel,Mountains,Hot Dogs,Cupcakes
```

and it should get stored as:

```
[John] = {Dog, DC, Beach, Hamburgers, Brownies}
[Sue]  = {Cat, DC, Beach, Hot Dogs, Brownies}
[Jim]  = {Dog, Marvel, Mountains, Hot Dogs, Cupcakes}
```

```
//specialized function for reading files
//stores the values in the file in a map with the participant's name as the key and a vector of
//strings as the value
map<string, vector<string> > readFile(fstream & f) {
    map<string, vector<string> > output;

    //variables for use in splitting the values stored in the .csv
    vector<string> row;
    string word, line;

    //reading the file
    while (!f.eof()) {
        row.clear();

        //reading the next line in the file
        getline(f, line);

        //removing the trailing newline character
        line.pop_back();

        //creating new string stream object using line
        //stringstream s(line);

/*
        //separating the contents of a line by commas and storing them in row
        while (getline(s, word, ',')) {
            row.push_back(word);
        }

        //removing the name from the beginning of the vector and storing it in a
        //separate variable
        string name = row[0];
        row.erase(row.begin());

        //adding new entry to output
        output[name] = row;
*/
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `f.eof()` won't return true until `getline` fails.  When `getline` reads the last line in the file, the getline succeeds, the file is positioned after the last byte, but `f.eof` is not yet set.  Thus, you are calling `line.pop_back()` on a zero-length string.

Instead, use this idiom:

```
    while( getline(f, line) )
    {
        row.clear()
        ...
```